# How to get port information from DOT files

Tags: python, graph, pygraphviz

I have the below topology DOT file (test.dot). This dot file maintains a network topology in Switch-port name  manner.

```
digraph G {
   "R1":"swp1" -> "R3":"swp3"; // Port swp1 of switch R1 is connected to port swp3 of R3
   "R1":"swp2" -> "R4":"swp3";
   "R1":"swp3" -> "R5":"swp3";
   "R1":"swp4" -> "R6":"swp3";
 }
```

I am using pygraphviz library in python to read the graph.

Source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pygraphviz import *

G = AGraph("test.dot")

for edge in G.edges():
    print edge
```

OUTPUT:

```
(u'R1', u'R6')
(u'R1', u'R4')
(u'R1', u'R3')
(u'R1', u'R5')
```

The issue I am facing is that the API doesn't gives the port information.
How can I get the port information also from the API ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very slick interface.  But you can get the data this way:

```
In [2]: G.get_edge('R1','R3').attr['headport']
Out[2]: u'swp3'

In [3]: for e in G.edges():
    print e,e.attr
   ...:     
(u'R1', u'R3') {u'tailport': u'swp1', u'headport': u'swp3'}
(u'R1', u'R4') {u'tailport': u'swp2', u'headport': u'swp3'}
(u'R1', u'R5') {u'tailport': u'swp3', u'headport': u'swp3'}
(u'R1', u'R6') {u'tailport': u'swp4', u'headport': u'swp3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below fragment does the work.

`for edge in G.edges():
    print edge
    print "edge-ports:",
    print edge.attr.get("headport", None)`